# Network settings

Tags: networking, network-manager, system-settings

I have a problem. When I type `ifconfig` I only get lo, no trace for ens33.

How can I manage this please ? Thanks.

ps: I put the network adapter into Bridge mode

Comment: `ifconfig` is deprecated, and no longer included with a stock install of Ubuntu. Try using `ip` instead. See `man ip` for the instructions.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with more context. What is your Ubuntu version? Are you using a virtual machine (since you mention putting the adapter in bridge mode)? if so, which one (vmware? virtualbox?)